# Logic unit tests crash

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, unit-testing

I'm following this guide about **logic** unit testing:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html

I've added tests to my existing project just as in instruction, but when i try to run them in simulator, I'm getting this error:

[image: Crash]

Stack trace:
[image: Stack trace]

Also, I've tried to create completely new project and repeat procedure, but the problem remains. **Application** unit testing runs as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, Xcode 4.3 set the **LLDB** as a default debugger in all of your schemes, I changed it to **GDB** (Product->Edit Scheme->Test->Debugger) and the problem disappears. Why it causes the crash is another interesting question.