# App works for ios 4.3 simulator, but not ios 5 simulator. Any ideas?

Tags: ios, simulator

My app runs fine in the ios 4.3 simulator, but not the ios 5 simulator. I have ios 5 on my iPhone, and my app DOES work on the iPhone.

The app compiles fine in all of these three environments.

In the ios5 simulator, I get the following cryptic thread crash reports.

mig_get_reply_port appears to be the method call with a

> 0x935d5ef3  <+0012>  test   %eax,%eax
>
> "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Is this a configuration issue?

```
 - #0   0x00000000 in <????> ()
   #1   0x935d5ef3 in mig_get_reply_port ()
   #2   0x935cf70c in mach_ports_lookup ()
   #3   0x01d4b124 in _xpc_domain_init_local ()
   #4   0x01d48eb1 in _libxpc_initializer ()
   #5   0x8feaa203 in __dyld__ZN16ImageLoaderMachO18doModInitFunctionsERKN11ImageLoader11LinkContextE
   ()
   #6   0x8fea9d68 in __dyld__ZN16ImageLoaderMachO16doInitializationERKN11ImageLoader11LinkContextE
   ()
   #7   0x8fea72c8 in __dyld__ZN11ImageLoader23recursiveInitializationERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListE
   ()
   #8   0x8fea725e in __dyld__ZN11ImageLoader23recursiveInitializationERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListE
   ()
   #9   0x8fea725e in __dyld__ZN11ImageLoader23recursiveInitializationERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListE
   ()
   #10  0x8fea725e in __dyld__ZN11ImageLoader23recursiveInitializationERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListE
   ()
   #11  0x8fea725e in __dyld__ZN11ImageLoader23recursiveInitializationERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListE
   ()
   #12  0x8fea725e in __dyld__ZN11ImageLoader23recursiveInitializationERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListE
   ()
   #13  0x8fea725e in __dyld__ZN11ImageLoader23recursiveInitializationERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListE
   ()
   #14  0x8fea8268 in __dyld__ZN11ImageLoader15runInitializersERKNS_11LinkContextERNS_21InitializerTimingListE
   ()
   #15  0x8fe9c694 in __dyld__ZN4dyld24initializeMainExecutableEv ()
   #16  0x8fea0f99 in __dyld__ZN4dyld5_mainEPK12macho_headermiPPKcS5_S5_ ()
   #17  0x8fe9a2ef in __dyld__ZN13dyldbootstrap5startEPK12macho_headeriPPKclS2_ ()
   #18  0x8fe9a063 in __dyld__dyld_start ()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try looking at the stack trace to see if the offending call originated in your code.

Comment: Well the problem is that there was no stack trace b/c the error happened before main() was executed.  The fix here, just in case someone else has the issue is that I was linking to libxml2.dylib; somewhere on stackoverflow I got the idea to upgrade that to libxml2.2.7.3.dylib, and now my app works in ios 4.3 and ios 5 simulators, and on a phone running ios 5. I was using xmppframework. Note that using libxml2 while also linking to libresolv.dylib does not work.  But I knew that I had to keep libresolv.dylib in the project build settings, it was not negotiable.  YMMV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a duplicate of questions asked earlier. Check out:

[iOS App crashing before entering main() with Xcode 4.2 & iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710163/ios-app-crashing-before-entering-main-with-xcode-4-2-ios-5)

[Application crashes on simulator 5.0 before reaching main.m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595908/application-crashes-on-simulator-5-0-before-reaching-main-m)

Also, this seems to indicate that this is ultimately a bug in the simulator:

http://www.openradar.me/10464051

Comment: Thanks alot! I am totally fine with the bug being in the simulator. Rarely do I get to rejoice that finally it's not me doing something wrong. Apple, please fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing libxml2 to libxml2.2.7.3 worked amongst the various solutions  ! :)